# Can I choose two geographic target countries for my website?

Tags: google-search-console, internationalization, geotargeting, country-specific, international

I have a website, the main target audience from two countries. In the Google Webmaster Tools you just can choose one location.

Do I need to do something or just leave it alone?

Comment: But having 2 identical pages:
www.example.com/
www.example.com/uk/ wouldn't Google take this as duplication and punish you for it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can [geotarget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotargeting) a website to multiple counties, but first you must split the website into country specific sections, either using sub-domains or sub-directories. Then these sections of the site can be separately geotargeted in Google Webmaster Tools.

e.g.:

You might have your main website that targets the US: `www.example.com`.

Then if you wanted to geotarget the UK, you would need to create either a sub-domain or sub-folder such as:

```
www.example.com/uk/
uk.example.com/
```

Then in Google Webmaster Tools, you can select the sub-directory or sub-domain and apply the geo-target.

More info on multinational websites and geotargeting can be found [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62399) and [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192).